# why javafx ignore return from main and still launches an application?

Tags: java, javafx, return, program-entry-point

I have the following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    if (!ArgumentsHandler.handle(args))
    {
        return;
    }

    Storage.getInstance().load();

    if (!Storage.getInstance().isLoadSuccessful())
    {
        launch(args);
    }
    else
    {
        System.err.println("Unable to load configurations.");
    }
}
```

I've specifically inverter the condition inside the `if` statement to fail it and I can definitely see in the debugger that it does not execute the `launch` method, yet the application window is still being shown.

I've also notices that using `return` statement inside `main` method has no effect - application still continues to execute. It only responds to `System.exit(0)`.

Why is this happening?

Update:

As you requested, here is a snippet of ArgumentsHandler. Nowhere here do I use threads (at least intentionally).

```
public static boolean handle(String[] args)
{
    //handle args
    if (args.length > 0)
    {
        switch (args[0])
        {
            //createRepository
            case "-c":
                configure(args);
                break;
            case "-r":
            case "--repository":
                repository(args);
                break;
            default:
                help();
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private static void configure(String[] args)
{
    if (args.length > 1)
    {
        boolean isRandom = false;

        switch (args[1])
        {
            case "true":
            case "1":
                isRandom = true;
                break;
            case "false":
            case "0":
                //valid input, ignored
                break;
            default:
                System.err.println("Invalid arguments. Possible values: [--configuration] [1/0].");
                return;
        }

        Storage.configure(isRandom); //creates a bunch of json files (uses NIO).
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        System.err.println("Invalid arguments. Possible values: -c [1/0].");
    }
}
```

Storage

```
public void load()
{
    isLoadSuccessful = false;

    //load configuration
    app = loadConfiguration(appFilePath);

    if (app == null)
    {
        System.err.println("Unable to load app configuration.");
        return;
    }

    //load company
    company = loadCompany(app.getCompanyFilePath());

    if (company == null)
    {
        System.err.println("Unable to load company configuration.");
        return;
    }

    repository = loadRepository(app.getRepositoryFilePath());

    if (repository == null)
    {
        System.err.println("Unable to load repository configuration.");
        return;
    }

    isLoadSuccessful = true;
}

private static App loadConfiguration(String filePath)
{
    return (App) Utility.load(filePath, App.class);
}
```

`loadConfiguration`, `loadCompany` and `loadRepository` are really the same. In the future, they would not read simple json files, but would access complex archives that's why I've already created several nearly identical methods.

Utility.load

```
public static Object load(String path, Type type)
{
    try
    {
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(path));
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Object obj = gson.fromJson(reader, type);
        reader.close();

        return obj;
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Just deserializes object from file.

Comment: Could you please show the code snippets of `ArgumentsHandler.handle(...)` and `Storage.load()`? I assume that one of these methods spawn a non-daemon thread which prevents the process from being ended after leaving the `main` method.

Comment: The main method is called from the main thread, just because you `return` doesnt mean you exited the thread. You havn't progress far enough to launch the window, but haven't explicitly told the thread to exit either, thus you get a application stall. Im not sure what you are trying to do in the `main` method, but if you are trying to `return`, then you probably want to exit anyways.

Comment: @trylimits added to the question.

Comment: You can check if there are other threads running (besides the main thread) while debugging. If you use _Eclipse_ you can see the running threads in the _Debug View_: https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-debug_view.htm

Comment: From the way you call `launch` I'm assuming `main` is in an `Application` subclass. I've found having `main` inside your `Application` class causes some sort of initialization that prevents the JVM from exiting once `main` has exited. This happens despite not calling `launch`. I'm guessing this has something to do with the special way Java launches JavaFX applications because moving `main` to another class doesn't cause this problem. And it's not caused by the `Application` class because initializing that class manually also doesn't cause this problem.

Comment: On the contrary, @HypnicJerk, the top-level invocation of `main()` exiting exactly does tell the main thread to exit.  But that does not mean there are no other non-daemon threads in the application, and in a GUI application there ordinarily is at least one other.  The overall application will not terminate until all non-daemon threads have exited.

Comment: @Slaw Yea, `main` in located inside Application class (it's child).
Actually, there are a lot of different threads running, namely "JavaFX Application thread", "QuantumRenderer", "ReferenceHandler", "Signal Dispatcher" and two unnamed threads: "Thread1" and "Thread3" - both are doing nothing really. Just waiting for some mutex and their call stacks do not contain any meaningful methods.

Comment: Java must initialize the JavaFX runtime automatically if the main class is a subclass of `Application`. You can try moving `main` to a separate class and use `Application.launch(Class,String[])` or try calling `Platform.exit()` before returning from `main`.

Comment: @Slaw that's what I did - I wrote `System.exit(); return;`. But it feels super dirty and do not fully understand why does it not work - that's why I've posted this question. I've never encountered stuff like this Swing and on Android.

Comment: Quick clarification: Are you saying, even if `launch` is not called, that `Application.start` is still being invoked and an actual `Stage` is being shown? Because I can't reproduce that behavior. I _can_ reproduce the JavaFX runtime being initialized even if `launch` is not called.

Comment: @Staw yes, `launch` is not being called, yet the window still shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way you are calling `launch(args)` I'm assuming, and you later [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52211807/why-javafx-ignore-return-from-main-and-still-launches-an-application#comment91374226_52211807) this, that the `main` method is in a subclass of `Application`. I believe this is the cause of your issue.

As you've noted there are a lot of seemingly JavaFX-specific threads running. Specifically, the non-daemon "JavaFX Application Thread" is running (at least, it's non-daemon in Java 10). This thread will cause the JVM to remain alive even if the `main` thread exits. This is normal behavior for Java:

> **java.lang.Thread**
>
> When a Java Virtual Machine starts up, there is usually a single non-daemon thread (which typically calls the method named `main` of some designated class). The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute threads until either of the following occurs:
>
> - The `exit` method of class `Runtime` has been called and the security manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
> - All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning from the call to the `run` method or by throwing an exception that propagates beyond the `run` method.

But why is the "JavaFX Application Thread" started when you have deliberately not called `Application.launch` yet? I'm just guessing here but it probably has to do with the special treatment JavaFX applications receive. Since at least Java 8 you don't have to declare a `main` method inside a subclass of `Application`<sup>1</sup>. If the main class is a subclass of `Application` Java handles the launching automatically.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // create scene and show stage...
    }

}
```

If you have the above and call `java MyApp` the application will launch and `start` will be called. However, if you have the below:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // create scene and show stage...
    }

}
```

Then the `main` method is called but `start` is *not*. Basically, explicitly declaring `main` overrides the default behavior of launching the JavaFX application *but doesn't stop the JavaFX runtime from being initialized*. Maybe this behavior is as designed or maybe it's an oversight. But the important thing here is this only happens if the main class has a `main` method and is an `Application` subclass. If you separate those two:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    // implement ...
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Perform pre-checks, return if necessary
        Application.launch(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Then you will no longer have this problem.

Otherwise you can continue using `System.exit()` or switch to `Platform.exit()`.

---

There's another, maybe more appropriate, way to handle this. You seem to be performing initialization in the `main` method before calling `Application.launch`. If something goes wrong during this initialization you want to abort launching the JavaFX application. Well, JavaFX provides the means to do this itself: [`Application.init()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/application/Application.html#init()).

> The application initialization method. This method is called immediately after the Application class is loaded and constructed. An application may override this method to perform initialization prior to the actual starting of the application.
>
> The implementation of this method provided by the Application class does nothing.
>
> NOTE: This method is not called on the JavaFX Application Thread. An application must not construct a Scene or a Stage in this method. An application may construct other JavaFX objects in this method.

Move your initialization code to this method. If you call [`Platform.exit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#exit()) then the application will exit and `Application.start` won't be invoked. An alternative is to throw an exception inside `init`. You can also get the application arguments by using [`Application.getParameters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters()) which returns an instance of [`Application.Parameters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/application/Application.Parameters.html).

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        if (!ArgumentsHandler.handle(getParameters()) {
            Platform.exit(); // or throw an exception
        } else {
            Storage storage = Storage.getInstance();
            storage.load();
            if (!storage.isLoadSuccessful()) {
                Platform.exit(); // or throw an exception
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // Create Scene and show the primary Stage
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        /*
         * Called when the JavaFX application is exiting, such as from
         * a call to Platform.exit(). Note, however, that in my experience
         * this method is *not* called when Platform.exit() is called inside
         * the "init" method. It is called if Platform.exit() is called from
         * inside the "start" method or anywhere else in the application once
         * it is properly started.
         *
         * This is where you could perform any necessary cleanup.
         */
    }

}
```

---

<sup>1. JavaFX was included with Java SE in version 8. Note this behavior may change in Java 11 since JavaFX is to be separate from Java SE again.</sup>